# Does the Google Analytics SDK use SSL?

Tags: ios, ssl, encryption, google-analytics, app-store

**Does the SDK for Google Analytics uses SSL**, and thus would need an encryption approval letter for use in an iPhone app?

In case their is any confusion, [Apple does require an export compliance letter for SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128927/using-ssl-in-an-iphone-app-export-compliance)

Answer (score 7):

It appears to be a **NO**. How did I arrive at this conclusion? first I found that for Google Analytics to use SSL, it has to send all data to the `https:` version of google's server. See: https://www.sslshopper.com/article-enable-ssl-for-google-analytics.html . Then I found a blog post where someone monitored google analytics' connection(s) through iOS, and it ***wasn't*** using `https:`.

See: [Monitor Google Analytics requests on an iPhone Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473166/monitor-google-analytics-requests-on-an-iphone-application) and http://jordan.broughs.net/archives/2012/07/monitoring-google-analytics-for-ios.